# Files.isReadable & network resolution

Tags: java, windows, nio

Given an OS Windows 7 Enterprise (SP 1) 32-bit and JDK 1.7.0_25,

Running the following Groovy code `println Files.isReadable(Paths.get("foo.txt"))` prints *true*

The file resides on a local drive (within the same folder as the Groovy script)

However, once I unplug the network cable and rerun, it prints *false*

Can anyone shed a light on it?

Comment: Did anyone else cringe when they saw the JDK version number, thinking it was the JRE version?

Comment: What is the entire path to that file?

Comment: @EJP it's `C:\tt\foo.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If the file is on a network share (Samba, potentially, but especially DFS mapped to a network drive on Windows/mount point on Linux) then pulling the network cable will indeed result in the file not being readable due to the inaccessibility of the server holding it.

If the file is not on a (mapped) network drive then something else is at play.

Comment: Thanks, but the file is on local drive, had forgotten to mention it

Comment: @orid Does pulling the cable cause inaccessibility for *other* programs?

Comment: Of course but as expected. I'm just puzzled how come it happens on a local drive `Files.isAccessible` throws `IOException`, but without Debug info, can't really see into it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
Path p = Paths.get("foo.txt"));
System.out.println(p.toString());
```

Then see what it prints out for the actual path. Maybe it's not local?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it's local. Have already check such trivial things